# Add shadows to bottoms tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code to create the tabs (bottom), works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Tab 1 content -->
            <include layout="@layout/tab1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <!-- Tab 2 content -->
            <include layout="@layout/tab2" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

I have added the elevation property in multiple ways (to the tabs, tabHost, to the layout ...) and none of them works. I have found some solutions here but none works for me. Any ideas for this particular code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elevation property works only for views with background, but your views are transparent. You can try to set background and elevation to your TabHost, or put the whole tab bar into the AppBarLayout.

Comment: Thank you! I have wrapped the layout of the tabs in a linear-layout with a background and elevation and it works fine.